# How do I run ClojureScripts Om on Node.js?

Tags: node.js, clojurescript, om

I'm trying to work out if I can use Om on Node.js to generate HTML.  I've been able to get [ClojureScript running on Node.js](https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/wiki/Quick-Start) and apparently [React can be run on Node.js](https://scotch.io/tutorials/build-a-real-time-twitter-stream-with-node-and-react-js).
I create a Leiningen project as follows as per the [basic guide](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Basic-Tutorial)

```
lein new figwheel om-tut -- --om
```

modified the project.clj file to start as follows

```
(defproject om-tut "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :description "FIXME: write this!"
  :url "http://example.com/FIXME"
  :license {:name "Eclipse Public License"
            :url "http://www.eclipse.org/legal/epl-v10.html"}

  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.6.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-2850"]
                 [figwheel "0.2.5-SNAPSHOT"]
                 [org.clojure/core.async "0.1.346.0-17112a-alpha"]
                 [sablono "0.3.4"]
                 [org.omcljs/om "0.8.8"]]

  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "1.0.4"]
            [lein-figwheel "0.2.5-SNAPSHOT"]
            [lein-npm "0.4.0"]]

  :source-paths ["src"]

  :clean-targets ^{:protect false} ["resources/public/js/compiled" "out/server" "out/server/om_tut.js"]

  :cljsbuild {
    :builds [{:id "dev"
              :source-paths ["src" "dev_src"]
              :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/om_tut.js"
                         :output-dir "resources/public/js/compiled/out"
                         :optimizations :none
                         :main om-tut.dev
                         :asset-path "js/compiled/out"
                         :source-map true
                         :source-map-timestamp true
                         :cache-analysis true }}
             {:id "min"
              :source-paths ["src"]
              :compiler {:output-to "resources/public/js/compiled/om_tut.js"
                         :main om-tut.core                         
                         :optimizations :advanced
                         :pretty-print false}}
             {:id "server"
              :source-paths ["src"]
              :compiler {
                :main pow.core
                :output-to "out/server/om_tut.js"
                :output-dir "out/server"
                :optimizations :simple
                :target :nodejs
                :cache-analysis true
                :source-map "out/server/om_tut.js.map"}}]}
```

and changed core.cljs to

```
(ns ^:figwheel-always om-tut.core
    (:require[om.core :as om :include-macros true]
              [om.dom :as dom :include-macros true]))

(enable-console-print!)

(println "Edits to this text should show up in your developer console.")

;; define your app data so that it doesn't get over-written on reload

(defonce app-state (atom {:text "Hello world!"}))

(defn render [data owner]
  (reify om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (dom/h1 nil (:text data)))))

(om/root
  render
  app-state
  {:target (. js/document (getElementById "app"))})

(defn -main []
  om.dom/render-to-str (render app-state nil))

(set! *main-cli-fn* -main)
```

The project compiles successfully using the following command

```
lein cljsbuild once server
```

but when I try to run the generate output like so from a Windows cmd shell

```
node out\server\om_tut.js
```

I get

```
    ...\om-tut\out\server\om_tut.js:40237
om.dom.input = om.dom.wrap_form_element.call(null, React.DOM.input, "input");
                                                   ^
ReferenceError: React is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (...\om-tut\out\server\
om_tut.js:40237:52)
    at Module._compile (module.js:460:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:478:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:355:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:310:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:501:10)
    at startup (node.js:129:16)
    at node.js:814:3
```

I think the React object that is undefined is supposed to come from the ...\om-tut\out\react.inc.js file which exists and should have been loaded at line 37532 of the generated om_tut.js file

```
cljs.core.load_file("react.inc.js");
```

Any ideas about what might be going wrong?

Comment: node.js is on server and it can serve some html/js files which can be generated by clojurescript/om.. So what does react can be `run on` node.js means ?

Comment: Node.js runs JavaScript (not just serves it), ClojureScript compiles down into JavaScript and Om is a library for ClojureScript.  I want to use the awesomeness that is Om to generate the HTML that I'll serve up to the web for those browsers that don't support JavaScript.

Comment: have you tried first if emitted JS runs in the browser ? may be it requires first some call to download `react` itself that would happen with the browser..

Comment: Did you get any errors that could indicate that there was a problem loading ReactJS code? Maybe it uses JS API that is only available in the browser JS?

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to add a preamble to `project.clj`, e.g. `:preamble ["include.js"]`. Preambles implicitly reference the `/resources` directory relative to `project.clj`. Source: https://github.com/Sparrho/supper/blob/master/project.clj

Within `include.js` you'll provide a reference to React:

```
var React = require("react");
```

Source: https://github.com/Sparrho/supper/blob/master/resources/include.js

For reference, here's the build block from project.clj:

```
{:id "server"
:source-paths ["src"]
:compiler {:main myapp.core-server
           :target :nodejs
           :output-to "deploy/index.js"
           :output-dir "out-server"
           :preamble ["include.js"] ;; Implicitly nested in /resources                       
           :optimizations :simple
           :language-in :ecmascript5
           :language-out :ecmascript5}}
```

I've also read that `:preamble` can reference `react.min.js` directly as it's been bundled in a WebJar on which Om takes a dependency. Source: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/clojurescript/TL8Cv-jPkzM

Answer (score 1):

You could try workaround `:preamble ["include.js"]` with following content:

```
module.exports = '';
```

But it's appropriate only in case when you have only some of `cljsjs/` packages (in this case it's `cljsjs/react`). For example including of `cljsjs/jquery 2.1.4` won't work.

---

Problem appears because of React definition:

```
!function(e){
    if ("object" == typeof exports && "undefined" != typeof module) {
        module.exports = e();
    }
    else if ("function" == typeof define && define.amd) {
        define([],e);
    }
    else{
        var t;
        t= "undefined" != typeof window ? window
            : "undefined" != typeof global ? global
            : "undefined" != typeof self ? self
            : this,
            t.React = e()
    }
}(function(){/* React definition */})
```

Environment doesn't have `window` object in NodeJS but it has `module` and `module.exports`. We lie to environment by resetting `module.exports` to string.

`React = require('react')` doesn't work out of NpmJS environment with installed `react` module.

---

In my opinion the correct solution would be not to include code of React to module, but use this module under NpmJS environment which has `react` in dependencies.

In this case [tyronep's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4922956/tyronep)
answer is good. We should:

1. use following `:preamble`:

   ```
   global.React = require('react')
   ```
2. don't include `cljsjs/react` to dependencies
3. require `react` in NpmJS dependencies.

Unfortunately if we want to use `om` then `cljsjs/react` *must* be included (that is redundant inclusion)

Answer (score 0):

Your current problem is about loading the React module which I'm sure you will solve tweaking your configuration, but you can't call `om.core/root` on Node. `om.core/root` mounts your React components in a DOM, which Node lacks. What you want is to define your components, pass them your static data and then call `React.renderToString`(https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/top-level-api.html#react.rendertostring). Om wraps it with [`render-to-str`](https://github.com/omcljs/om/wiki/Documentation#render-to-str).

```lisp
(def static-data {:text "Hello world!"})

(defn title-component [data owner]
  (reify om/IRender
    (render [_]
      (dom/h1 nil (:text data)))))

(def component-html-as-string
  (dom/render-to-str (title-component static-data)))
```

Most of Om's value comes from their state handling capabilities, which you won't need for server side rendering (that's why I omitted `atom`). If what you want is React templating in ClojureScript I suggest you look at [Sablono](https://github.com/r0man/sablono/) which has a [function for static html](https://github.com/r0man/sablono/blob/master/src/sablono/core.cljx#L76) and a nicer syntax for generating templates than `om.dom`.

Also, to develop on Node it is better to start from [mies-node](https://github.com/swannodette/mies-node-template)